# New technology areas in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Today on this website we can see documentation about general IT technologies, but we can't see industrial technologies. For example, we can't find documentation about Siemens languages (LIST, SCL ...) for industrial automation systems or documentation about industrial microcontroller programming.

It might be interesting to include industrial documentation on this website.

Comment: Sure, let me just wave my magic wand to add them! In all seriousness: the reason these don't exist (yet) is because nobody has written them, and asking on Meta isn't going to help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it's was to add new subject on the website about industrial technologie

Comment: Is this about our new Documentation sub-site? Or do you have a question about these technologies, and find that there are no tags for them? In the latter case - just post the question. If the tag is necessary, somebody with 1500 or more points will create it and add it.

Comment: These are pretty niche programming environments, not a lot of programmers work in that space and there are not a lot of questions about it.  Not in the least because Siemens already provides excellent documentation and support.  They have to, it is expected of vendors that sell their product at a premium price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are programming languages and fall within Stack Overflow's scope. But it's a long way for them to appear in Documentation. For a new technology area to have Documentation, there need to be [some questions first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-add-tags):

> Because we only want to document things that developers are actually using, documentation is tied to existing tags from Q&A.

The [scl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scl) tag doesn't exist, and the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) tag isn't about the language. First, they have to be created, which is only possible if you have a question about LIST or SCL which is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, then somebody with [1500 or more reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) could create the tag. Only then will it be possible to write Documentation about these languages here.

This sounds a bit cumbersome, but that's good: we're looking for high quality content, and you need more than a few users for that. It seems the Siemens community has its own Q&A site (or a forum), just like e.g. the SAP/ABAP community.

Comment: You also need >600 questions and >3/day to enable Docs, I think.